# Tomcat6 libs and /usr/share/java on Ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, tomcat6

I've faced with strange tomcat6 behavior. Tomcat uses jar files from both **/usr/share/tomcat6/lib** and **/usr/share/java**. It's not good for me because a also have installed maven and **/usr/share/java** contains few versions of each java library and some applications cannot start because they see all version of libraries.

How I can disable using of **/usr/share/java** by Tomcat6?

p.s. I use Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Listen to me - the best thing to deal with java & (ubunu | debian) if you remove all java from the distribution and make an independent install, downloaded from the net.

Comment: That's what i've done first. I just downloaded jdk*.jar.gz archive, unpacked it and updated system paths to use java. But now tomcat uses /usr/share/java and I cannot find any dependency from tomcat to this directory.

Comment: If you did this really, there weren't any jar files in /usr/share/tomcat6 and in /usr/share/java . Even this directories didn't exist. You should remove _all_ packages, which contains "java" in their name. And you should install your independent java as user, in a separate directory.